# Storing multiple image url's into sqlite as blob

Tags: android, image, sqlite, url

I want to store multiple url's in SQLite as blob.
The code below is what I have now, but this only convert the url's in a sqlite into a image. Can someone help me with this?

database.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursorDriver;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Provides access to the vvz4 database. Since this is not a Content Provider,
 * no other applications will have access to the database.
 */
public class VVZ4Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    /** The name of the database file on the file system */
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "vvz4";
    /** The version of the database that this class understands. */
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    /** Keep track of context so that we can load SQL from string resources */
    private final Context mContext;

    static final String LOG_TAG = "VVZ4";


    // #######################################################################################
    // #######################################################################################
    /** Constructor */
    public VVZ4Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.mContext = context;

    }

    /**
     * Execute all of the SQL statements in the String[] array
     * 
     * @param db
     *            The database on which to execute the statements
     * @param sql
     *            An array of SQL statements to execute
     */
    private void execMultipleSQL(SQLiteDatabase db, String[] sql) {
        for (String s : sql)
            if (s.trim().length() > 0)
                db.execSQL(s);
    }

    /** Called when it is time to create the database */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String[] sql = mContext.getString(R.string.VVZ4Database_onCreate)
                .split("\n");
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            // Create tables & test data
            execMultipleSQL(db, sql);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("Error creating tables and debug data", e.toString());
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    }

    /** Called when the database must be upgraded */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(VVZ4Database.LOG_TAG, "Upgrading database from version "
                + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
                + ", which will destroy all old data");

        String[] sql = mContext.getString(R.string.VVZ4Database_onUpgrade)
                .split("\n");
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            // Create tables & test data
            execMultipleSQL(db, sql);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("Error creating tables and debug data", e.toString());
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }

        // This is cheating. In the real world, you'll need to add columns, not
        // rebuild from scratch
        onCreate(db);
    }

    // #######################################################################################
    // ############# SPELERS
    // #############################################################
    public void addSpelers(String firstname, String lastname, String age, String wasdienst, String fluitdienst, String phone, String foto) {
        String sql = String.format(
                "INSERT INTO spelers (firstname, lastname, age, wasdienst, fluitdienst, phone, foto) "
                        + "VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s , %s, %s)",
                DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(firstname),
                DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(lastname),
                DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(age),
                DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(wasdienst),
                DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(fluitdienst),
                DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(phone),
                DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(foto));
        try {
            getWritableDatabase().execSQL(sql);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("Error writing new spelers", e.toString());
        }
    }   
    // 
    // ################ SPELERS
    // ################################################################
    public void deleteAllSpelers() {
        String sql = "DELETE from spelers";
        try {
            getWritableDatabase().execSQL(sql);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("Error deleting all spelers", e.toString());
        }
    }   

    // 
    // ################ SPELERS
    // ################################################################
    public SpelersCursor getSpelers() {
        String sql = SpelersCursor.QUERY;
        SQLiteDatabase d = getReadableDatabase();
        SpelersCursor c = (SpelersCursor) d.rawQueryWithFactory(
                new SpelersCursor.Factory(), sql, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }

    public static class SpelersCursor extends SQLiteCursor {

        private static final String QUERY = "SELECT _id, firstname, lastname, age, wasdienst, fluitdienst, phone, foto "
            + "FROM spelers " + "ORDER BY _id ";

        private SpelersCursor(SQLiteDatabase db, SQLiteCursorDriver driver,
                String editTable, SQLiteQuery query) {
            super(db, driver, editTable, query);
        }

        private static class Factory implements SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory {
            @Override
            public Cursor newCursor(SQLiteDatabase db,
                    SQLiteCursorDriver driver, String editTable,
                    SQLiteQuery query) {
                return new SpelersCursor(db, driver, editTable, query);
                }
            }

        public String getColFirstname() {
            return getString(getColumnIndexOrThrow("firstname"));
        }

            public String getColLastname() {
                return getString(getColumnIndexOrThrow("lastname"));
            }

            public String getColAge() {
                return getString(getColumnIndexOrThrow("age"));
            }

            public String getColWasdienst() {
                return getString(getColumnIndexOrThrow("wasdienst"));
            }

            public String getColFluitdienst() {
                return getString(getColumnIndexOrThrow("fluitdienst"));
            }

            public String getColPhone() {
                return getString(getColumnIndexOrThrow("phone"));
            }

            public String getColFoto() {
                return getString(getColumnIndexOrThrow("foto"));
            }
        }
}
```

Activity.java

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.vvz4.app.VVZ4Database.SpelersCursor;

//import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
//import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
//import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.util.Linkify;
import android.util.Log;
//import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
//import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
//import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
//import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SpelersActivity extends ListActivity {

    private final int VVZ4_MAX_SPELERS = 20;
    public static final String KEY_121 = "http://www.vvz4.nl/ripper/vvz4fluiten.php";
    private int iNumSpelers = 0;

    private VVZ4Database VVZ4_database;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private ImageButton btnRefresh;

//  private float downXValue;

    public class Vvz4Spelers {
        public String firstname;
        public String lastname;
        public String age;
        public String wasdienst;
        public String fluitdienst;
        public String phone;
        public String foto;

        Vvz4Spelers(String firstname, String lastname, String age, String wasdienst, String fluitdienst, String phone, String foto) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.lastname = lastname;
            this.age = age;
            this.wasdienst = wasdienst;
            this.fluitdienst = fluitdienst;
            this.phone = phone;
            this.foto = foto;
        }
    };

    Vvz4Spelers[] spelersListData;
    Vvz4Spelers[] spelersInternetData;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spelers);

        // setTitle(getString(R.string.wedstrijden));

        VVZ4_database = new VVZ4Database(this);

        btnRefresh = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRefresh);

        btnRefresh.setOnClickListener(btnRefreshOnClick);

        // maak een array aan om alle spelers in te zetten
        spelersListData = new Vvz4Spelers[VVZ4_MAX_SPELERS];
        spelersInternetData = new Vvz4Spelers[VVZ4_MAX_SPELERS];

        // zet spelers uit database in list
        FillListFromDB();

        // probeer ook nieuwe spelers info op te halen
        mHandler.postDelayed(mInternetTask, 1000);

        getListView().setDividerHeight(2);

        //getListView().setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    private final ImageButton.OnClickListener btnRefreshOnClick = new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mInternetTask, 100);
        }
    };

    private void FillListFromDB() {

        // wissen array
        for (int i = 0; i < VVZ4_MAX_SPELERS; i++) {
            spelersListData[i] = new Vvz4Spelers("", "", "", "", "", "", "");
        }

        // open cursor om door alle records heen te lopen
        SpelersCursor wC = VVZ4_database.getSpelers();

        Log.e("---->VVZ4 aantal wedstrijd records in database: ",
                String.format("%d", wC.getCount()));

        // vul array met data uit database
        int iRecord = 0;
        while (!wC.isAfterLast()) {

            if (iRecord >= VVZ4_MAX_SPELERS) {
                break;
            } // array is full

            spelersListData[iRecord].firstname = wC.getColFirstname();
            spelersListData[iRecord].lastname = wC.getColLastname();
            spelersListData[iRecord].age = wC.getColAge();
            spelersListData[iRecord].wasdienst = wC.getColWasdienst();
            spelersListData[iRecord].fluitdienst = wC.getColFluitdienst();
            spelersListData[iRecord].phone = wC.getColPhone();
            spelersListData[iRecord].foto = wC.getColFoto();

            iRecord++;

            // volgende record uit database
            wC.moveToNext();
        }
        iNumSpelers = iRecord;

        // close cursor
        wC.close();

        setListAdapter(new Vvz4SpelersDataAdapter(this));
    }

    private void LoadSpelersFromInternet() {

        // wissen array
        for (int i = 0; i < VVZ4_MAX_SPELERS; i++) {
            spelersInternetData[i] = new Vvz4Spelers("", "", "", "", "", "", "");
        }

        // haal de php data op
        String phpString = getServerData(SpelersActivity.KEY_121);

        int iNumLoadedFromInternet = 0;

        // parse json data
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(phpString);
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                if (i >= VVZ4_MAX_SPELERS) {
                    break;
                } // array is full
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String strFirstname = json_data.getString("firstname");
                String strLastname = json_data.getString("lastname");
                String strAge = json_data.getString("age");
                String strWasdienst = json_data.getString("wasdienst");
                String strFluitdienst = json_data.getString("fluitdienst");
                String strPhone = json_data.getString("phone");
                String strFoto = json_data.getString("foto");
                spelersInternetData[i].firstname = strFirstname;
                spelersInternetData[i].lastname = strLastname;
                spelersInternetData[i].age = strAge;
                spelersInternetData[i].wasdienst = strWasdienst;
                spelersInternetData[i].fluitdienst = strFluitdienst;
                spelersInternetData[i].phone = strPhone;
                spelersInternetData[i].foto = strFoto;
            }
            iNumLoadedFromInternet = i;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // alleen als er werkelijk spelers data van internet is geladen
        if (iNumLoadedFromInternet > 0) {

            // wis alle spelers records uit database
            VVZ4_database.deleteAllSpelers();
            Log.e("---->VVZ4 ", "Wissen alle spelers...");

            // vul database opnieuw
            for (int i = 0; i < iNumLoadedFromInternet; i++) {
                VVZ4_database.addSpelers(spelersInternetData[i].firstname, spelersInternetData[i].lastname, spelersInternetData[i].age, spelersInternetData[i].wasdienst,
                        spelersInternetData[i].fluitdienst, spelersInternetData[i].phone, spelersInternetData[i].foto);
                Log.e("---->VVZ4 Toevoegen wedstrijd: ", String.format(
                        "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s", spelersInternetData[i].firstname, spelersInternetData[i].lastname, spelersInternetData[i].age, spelersInternetData[i].wasdienst,
                        spelersInternetData[i].fluitdienst, spelersInternetData[i].phone, spelersInternetData[i].foto));
            }

            FillListFromDB();
        }
    }

    public class Vvz4SpelersDataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;

        public Vvz4SpelersDataAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return iNumSpelers;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return spelersListData[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }



        /**
         * Custom view translates columns into appropriate text, images etc.
         * 
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.widget.CursorAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
         *      android.view.ViewGroup)
         */
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                // sender is activity from where you call this adapter. Set it
                // with construktor.
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.spelersrow, null);
            }

            Vvz4Spelers item = (Vvz4Spelers) getItem(position);

            //LinearLayout llRow = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.llRow);
            TextView tvfirstname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblFirstname);
            TextView tvlastname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblLastname);
            TextView tvage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblAge);
            TextView tvwasdienst = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblWasdienst);
            TextView tvfluitdienst = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblFluitdienst);
            TextView tvphone = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblPhone);
            ImageView tvfoto = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblFoto);


            if (tvfirstname != null) {
                tvfirstname.setText(String.format("%s", item.firstname));
            }

            if (tvlastname != null) {
                tvlastname.setText(String.format("%s", item.lastname));
            }

            if (tvage != null) {
                tvage.setText(String.format("%s", item.age));
            }

            if (tvwasdienst != null) {
                tvwasdienst.setText(String.format("%s", item.wasdienst));
            }

            if (tvfluitdienst != null) {
                tvfluitdienst.setText(String.format("%s", item.fluitdienst));
            }

            if (tvphone != null) {
                tvphone.setText(String.format("%s", item.phone));
                Linkify.addLinks(tvphone, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
                tvphone.setLinkTextColor(Color.GREEN);              
            }

            try {
                String url1 = String.format("%s", item.foto);
                URL url = new URL(url1);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bfOptions.inDither = false; 
                bfOptions.inPurgeable = true; // Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
                bfOptions.inInputShareable = true; // Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future
                bfOptions.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
                Bitmap bmp = null;
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null,
                        bfOptions);
                tvfoto.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                connection.disconnect();
                input.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessError e) {
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            }


            return v;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // boolean supRetVal = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(1, 1, 0, "Wasdienst").setAlphabeticShortcut('4')
                .setIcon(R.drawable.internet);
        menu.add(1, 2, 1, "Fluitdienst").setAlphabeticShortcut('w')
                .setIcon(R.drawable.texttv);
        menu.add(1, 3, 2, "Home").setAlphabeticShortcut('v')
                .setIcon(R.drawable.internet);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 1:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, VVZ4WebViewActivity.class));
            return true;
        case 2:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, WedstrijdverslagenActivity.class));
            return true;
        case 3:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, VVZ4TabWidget.class));
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /**
     * Make sure to stop the animation when we're no longer on screen, failing
     * to do so will cause a lot of unnecessary cpu-usage!
     */
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(icicle);
    }

    private String getServerData(String returnString) {

        String result = "";
        // the year data to send
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("team","VVZ"));

        // http post
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            result = EntityUtils.toString(entity, HTTP.ISO_8859_1);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        return result;
    }


    private Runnable mInternetTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            LoadSpelersFromInternet();

        }
    };


}
```

Strings.xml

```
    <string name="VVZ4Database_onCreate">"
CREATE TABLE wedstrijden (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, datum TEXT, tijd TEXT, wedstrijd TEXT);
CREATE TABLE uitslagen (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, datum TEXT, thuis TEXT, uit TEXT, uitslag TEXT);
CREATE TABLE stand (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, plaats TEXT, elftal TEXT, g TEXT, w TEXT, gw TEXT, v TEXT, p TEXT, dpv TEXT, dpt TEXT, pm TEXT);
CREATE TABLE spelers (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT, age TEXT, wasdienst TEXT, fluitdienst TEXT, phone TEXT, foto BLOB);
"</string>
<string name="VVZ4Database_onUpgrade">"
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wedstrijden
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS uitslagen
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stand
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS spelers
"</string>
```

Comment: This is an awful lot of code for such a brief question. Can be more specific about what your problem is or where you are stuck? It's also nice to not just pour all you code in the question but to prepare a minimal example of your problem.

Comment: Yes i agree with Mr Gabriel.i am giving answer but next time remember

Answer (score 1):

**First**: If you want to store only image URL then no need of using blob

**Second**:IF you want to store image in data base then you have to download the image first and then convert it into bitmap and then in byte array.And while getting from data base then same reverse procedure will have to be followed

```
Code:  Download image from image_url
DataBaseHelper db=new DataBaseHelper(this);  //Contain  table
    SQLiteDatabase db1=db.getWritableDatabase();
    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.steve_jobs_tribute_feeldesain_021 );
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos);
    byte [] b=bos.toByteArray();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DataBaseHelper.Col1,b);

    int i=(int) db1.insert(DataBaseHelper.Table1, null,cv);  //saving image
    if(i!=-1){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Image Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Cursor cur=db1.query(DataBaseHelper.Table1, null,null,null,null,null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        byte [] b1=cur.getBlob(0);              // fetching image
       //ByteArrayInputStream bos1=new ByteArrayInputStream(b1s);
        Bitmap bitmap2=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b1, 0, b1.length);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }
```

**Now code for making 
`String str= "create table Table1("+Col1+" blob not null);";
        db.execSQL(str);`table**